# bash: basename: command not found on windows git

Tags: python, git-bash, python-venv

I'm working on a python project. My machine is Windows 10, 64 bit.
I have Git installed and from pycharm terminal I tried to call
`source venv\Scripts\activate`. As a result I get the error ***bash: basename: command not found \n()***. Yeah, those parenthesis appears one line below the error. In addition the branch name disappeared from the terminal prompt. From this point forehand all bash commands are no longer recognised by the terminal. Any attempt for ls, cp or source resulted in the same error message.

Restarting pycharm cause the bash shell to be active again with the branch name at the prompt but calling source shut it down with the same error.

Any idea how to fix this and activating venv properly?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, `basename` is a program and it just looks like you didn't install it.

Comment: basename is a program? I googled it and run "source venv\Scripts\activate.bat". This call run without causing bash to crush.

Comment: I don't see any crush anywhere, there's an error in a program you're calling, that's all. Also, yes, I just verified that `basename` is not a bash builtin command.

Answer (score 8):

Click on **File** and then on **Settings** option. Then, click on Tools in the left hand pane and then on Terminal from the options. There you'll see an option "Activate virtualenv". Uncheck it,

Comment: thks, it works.